# syntax error near unexpected token `((' in Sun Solaris Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, solaris

I have the following logic in the script Setup.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++))
do
  echo "Welcome $i times."
done
```

When I run the script using the command `./Setup.sh`, I get the error

```
./Setup.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `(('
./Setup.sh: line 3: `for ((i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++))'
```

When I run the script using the command sh Setup.sh , I get the error

```
Setup.sh: syntax error at line 3: `(' unexpected
```

When I run the script logic in Execute BASH Shell Script Online using http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php, it executes perfectly and prints the following.

```
Welcome 0 times.
Welcome 1 times.
Welcome 2 times.
Welcome 3 times.
Welcome 4 times.
```

Can someone help me understand why I get this error on Sun Solaris Unix machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `sh Setup.sh` the Solaris `/bin/sh` is used to execute the script. The Solaris `/bin/sh` is not a POSIX shell and also does not understand the non-portable `(())` syntax.

If you use `#!/bin/bash` it *should* work. If it doesn't, maybe your bash is very ancient. What does `bash --version` output?

The online demo uses bash `4.1.2(1)-release`.

Comment: bash --version
GNU bash, version 2.03.0(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris)
Copyright 1998 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Okay, 2.03 from 1998 **is very ancient** and obviously has no support for `(( ))`.

Comment: @Ravi The `for ((…; …; …))` syntax was added in bash 2.04.

Comment: Whether or not `/bin/sh` is POSIX is irrelevant, as the C-style `for` loop isn't part of the POSIX spec.

Comment: Newer versions of Solaris have newer versions of bash, but when you use older OS releases, you get older software.

Answer (score 1):

Please check which version of `bash` you have on the Solaris system.

```
bash --version
```

As far as I remember, the `(( ))` arithmetic notation was introduced recently. And it's a bashism, so it does not work with `sh`.

The website probably uses a new version of bash.

Comment: The `(( ... ))` here does establish an arithmetic context, but technically it is part of the C-style `for` loop syntax, not an arithmetic command (which would not recognize a `;` as a valid operator).